# How can I have multiple 'scripts' available to run multiple rules?

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment, rules

How can I have multiple 'scripts' available to run multiple rules? The only code that appears available to run with Rules/run a script is the code pasted in ThisOutlookSession. The modules below do not appear.

I have Outlook 2010 on Windows 11.
I'm accounts payable for my company.
All my invoices come in my email.

I have many vendors. I want to create rules that will save the attachments from specific vendors to the correct folder. Save attachments from joeshmo's email to the joeshmo folder in My Documents.

I have a couple working codes:

1. Where I select emails, run the macro and all attachments are saved to the same folder.
2. That I can use in a rule.

I re-enabled scripts for my version of Outlook.

I go to Rules, I set conditions, choose "run a script" and in the drop down, only one code is available, and that is whatever is pasted into "ThisOutlookSession".
When I open the VBA editor, there is a list of Modules but none of them appear in Run a script. Nor can I move them up there. I can only paste one code.

I want to create a Rule and accompanying script per Vendor to run automatically. So all the incoming emails with invoices are automatically saved to their folder.

Am I asking too much? I can save all attachments to the same folder and then sort.
Or I can create rules to assign categories to each vendor's email and then sort alphabetically. Meaning, I can select all the "A" vendors, run the macro, Select the "B" vendors, etc.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\Attachments\outlook testing\test number one"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Inside `saveAttachtoDisk` you could look at `itm` and decide where its attachments should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

"Run a script" expects the incoming item as input.

Code must start with something like `Sub somename(itm As Object)`.

You could create code for each vendor.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk_Sender1(itm As Object)

    ' Rule conditions: from Sender1 with attachment
    
    Dim objAtt As Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
    
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\Attachments\outlook testing\test number one"
    
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
    
End Sub

Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk_Sender2(itm As Object)

    ' Rule conditions: from Sender2 with attachment
    
    Dim objAtt As Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
    
    saveFolder = "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\Attachments\outlook testing\test number two"
        
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
    
End Sub
```

A single rule may be preferable:

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk_VariousSenders(itm As Object)

    ' Rule condition: with attachment
    
    Dim objAtt As Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat As String
    
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm")
    
    Debug.Print itm.senderEmailAddress
    Select Case itm.senderEmailAddress
    
        Case "sender1@someplace.com"
        saveFolder = "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\Attachments\outlook testing\test number one"
        
        Case "sender2@someplace.com"
        saveFolder = "C:\Users\jenny\Documents\Attachments\outlook testing\test number two"
        
        Case Else
        Debug.Print itm.senderEmailAddress & " not listed."
            
    End Select
    
    Debug.Print saveFolder
    If saveFolder <> "" Then
        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Next
    End If
    
End Sub
```